# Identifying the highest correlations values between independent variables and excluding the lowest correlation with the dependent variable in r

Tags: r, matrix, subset, correlation

I am trying to identify the highest correlation values among the independent variables (e.g.> = 0.8 | <= -0.8) and then exclude the **independent** variable that has the lowest correlation value with the **dependent** variable to avoid multicollinearity in linear models.

First I would like to identify the highest correlations between the independent variables and then exclude those that have the lowest correlations with the dependent variable that is in the first row and column called **EC1**

[The dataset if you want to run it](https://1drv.ms/t/s!Aj_3CRzoeUoIh64SUCOf_WKqPkRuxg?e=hz3P1P)

```
cor_26_EC<-rcorr(x=as.matrix(data_26_EM[c(4,8:length(data_26_EM))]),type="pearson")

cor_test<-(cor_26_EC$r)
```

```
> head(cor_test)
                     EC1         DEM       slope      aspect northernness   plan_curv   prof_curv convergence         twi
EC1           1.0000000 -0.68580505  0.36444948 -0.17735481   0.17735481 -0.14541592 -0.21159663 -0.10027208 -0.10220409
DEM          -0.6858051  1.00000000 -0.47325220  0.06090698  -0.06090698  0.28021257  0.34739247  0.24297883 -0.02919072
slope         0.3644495 -0.47325220  1.00000000 -0.02321129   0.02321129  0.04219001  0.01703231  0.03937512 -0.56400210
aspect       -0.1773548  0.06090698 -0.02321129  1.00000000  -1.00000000 -0.01574986 -0.01260762  0.04838931  0.02877949
northernness  0.1773548 -0.06090698  0.02321129 -1.00000000   1.00000000  0.01574986  0.01260762 -0.04838931 -0.02877949
plan_curv    -0.1454159  0.28021257  0.04219001 -0.01574986   0.01574986  1.00000000  0.59109001  0.73023077 -0.51818538

(it continues...)
```

Comment: If you expect multicollinearity in your data, rather than doing naive variable selection like this, consider using a model that explicitly deals with collinearity, such as ridge regression or the elastic net, or using Bayesian methods such as a g-prior

Comment: @alanocallaghan I'm sorry, I uploaded the wrong dataset. That was a simple dataset and I am having problems with this one.

Comment: @alanocallaghan I used my updated dataset and it worked fine, but I would like to know if the output values in **unique(drop_variables)** are the variables rated higher than the threshold and that was removed. Would it be this?

Comment: `drop_variables` would be the variables which you would remove using this method, though the code I wrote does not actually remove them from the data, just identify them. I'll repeat, **I would consider alternative approaches for feature selection in linear models as I think this is suboptimal**.

Comment: @alanocallaghan Do you have some workflow script or useful link about these approaches?

Comment: It's a very broad topic but the most accessible methods are L1 and L2 regularisation or combinations, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_net_regularization

Comment: btw if you find my answer useful feel free to upvote and/or accept it

Comment: I don't know what new data you are talking about? The linked data seems to be the same I looked at before

Comment: @alanocallaghan Do you know how can I subset/setdiff (or exclude) these variables from my original data frame?

Comment: `x[, setdiff(colnames(x), drop_variables)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want something along the lines of this:

```r
library("dplyr")
library("reshape2")

x <- read.delim("~/Documents/stack/EM_26.txt")
c <- cor(x)
## set diagonal to NA because we don't want autocorrelation
diag(c) <- NA
## reshape from matrix to long table
mdf <- melt(c)
## Choose max correlation for each variable
## You could also filter here by a threshold value, eg filter(abs(value) > 0.8)
max_cors <- mdf %>% group_by(Var1) %>% filter(value == max(value, na.rm = TRUE)) 
## For each max correlation, drop the one which has lower correlation with EC1
drop_variables <- apply(max_cors,
  1,
  function(row) {
    row[which.min(c(c["EC1", row[[1]]], c["EC1", row[[2]]]))]
  }
)
unique(drop_variables)
#> [1] "MS1"  "z"    "EC05"
```

Comment: By the way, if you are filtering to perform variable selection for modelling with (eg) regression, this is not a good approach!